# Can I use the Excel Data Model to expand many-to-many relational databses?

Tags: database, excel

**TL:DR;** Can I implement many-to-many relationship expansion in excel, without having to write them out myself. If so, how?

Here is a simplified variant of the problem I am trying to solve:

Suppose I have table of types:

Table1 Names:

```
ID, Name
1, T11
2, T12
3, T13
```

Now, there exists some other table of types which are dependent on the selections from `Table1`, let's call it `Table2`:

Table 2 Names:

```
ID, Table2 Name, Table1 Dependency
1, T21, 1
2, T21, 2
3, T22, 2
4, T23, 1
```

Table2-Table1 Dependency Table:

```
ID, Table1 Dependency
1, 1
2, 2
3, 2
4, 1
```

The above means that Item `T21` can is "enabled" iff item 1 (`T11`) *or* item 2 (`T12`) from `Table1` are selected, and `T22` is enabled iff item 2 (`T12`) from `Table1` is selected.

There are more tables, but for the sake of this question let's just add one more, `Table3` and its dependencies (this table depends on `Table1` and `Table2` items):

Table 3 names:

```
ID, Name
1, T31
2, T31
3, T32
```

Table3-Table2 Dependency Table:

```
ID, Table2 Dependency
1, 1
1, 2
2, 1
etc...
```

Table3-Table1 Dependency Table:

```
ID, Table1 Dependency
1, 1
1, 3
2, 1
etc...
```

The above would mean that in order for item 1 in `Table3` (`T31`) to be selected we would need to have *either* item 2 or item 1 from `Table2` *and* one of item 3 or item 1 from `Table1` selected.

As an output, I want 1 row for each possible combination `Table1` and `Table2` names that would lead to the respective item from `Table3` being enabled. Can I do this in Excel using relationships? If so, how? I've used SQL before but am not an expert.

Comment: I am sorry to say that using Excel to create databases is just a very bad thing to do. Excel was never meant to do this. Even using something as simple as Access sounds a lot better to me. In the end building databases in Excel is going to bite you in the ....

Comment: @Tom isn't the Excel Data Model supposed to do exactly this?

Comment: Over the years some database functionality has been added, this does not mean (in my opinion) that you should use Excel as a database program. I have seen many examples where this leads to problems in the long run. Better to use something like Access (not the ultimate database tool either, but at least meant to create databases) for the database and maybe use Excel as a front end.